# Communicating with Java Class from OpenLayers 3 UI?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, java, geotools

I have an OpenLayers 3 map and I am using Geoserver to host that map. So far, I have mostly frontend related tasks for my mapping application. Now, I need to include zonal statistics feature in my application. I was looking online and found that GeoServer/GeoTools [RasterZonalStatistics.Java](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-raster/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/raster/RasterZonalStatistics.java) file is what I need to compute my zonal statistics.

However, I don't know where to write my zonal statistics class.

How can I communicate with this Java class from OpenLayers UI?

For example, should I write my zonal statistics class in a separate eclipse project and host that Java file into GeoServer?

I tried to look online and came across GeoServer's [OWS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/ows-services/implementing.html) services. However, I am not sure if that's what I need to set up a correct backend class for my OpenLayers app.

How can I communicate with this Java class from my OpenLayers UI to calculate zonal statistics for my Tiff and shp file?

Comment: You need a wps process

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [WPS protocol](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/index.html) to ask GeoServer to run processes for you. If all you need are the ZonalStatistics then this [tutorial](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/raster_processes.html) will show you how.

If you want to develop your own processes then you need to follow this [section](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html) of the manual.